# How to add a delay to part of a script in Python?

Tags: python

I need to add a delay to part of a Python script, not the entire thing, but just a part.

Comment: What do you mean by delay? You want your script to just do nothing for a period of time?

Comment: Please show the code you wish to add a delay to.

Comment: Please provide more context: what are you trying to achieve and why do you believe that it requires a 'delay' ?

Comment: im now trying to add a proxy list for each login.. who can help with this

Comment: Please don't add things like `edit : solved. import time time.sleep(timehere)` to your questions: future readers will see the answer below for themselves. For more info on this topic please see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `time.sleep`:

```
import time

time.sleep(1) # Sleeps for one second.
```

Note that generally you don't want a real *delay*, but you want one thing to happen before the other. Using a delay to emulate ordering is bad code, and will break.